# dotCover Failed to Process Coverage Results in Continuous Testing

Tags: unit-testing, jetbrains-ide, dotcover

I have run into this issue "Failed to Process Coverage Results. The given key was not present in the dictionary."

This only happened in Continuous Testing. All the unit tests are MSTest. It used to work fine. I have Visual Studio 2017 Professional and ReSharper Ultimate suite 2017.3.5.

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Your running coverage locally using Resharper? Is there more to the failure message? NUnit version? Using DotCover?

Comment: @RobSmyth, I am running ReSharper locally with MSTest. This happened in Continuous Testing. All the unit tests are MSTest. It used to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by clicking dropping results in the current session ("Drop results" button on the toolbar) and re-run analysis.

Here is the original post:
https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000167744-Continuous-Testing-Failed-to-Process-Coverage-Results-The-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-